# How to keep list of image files in a var [] and send them to controller at once

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to send array of image files to a controller. Below I have sent one file to the controller, but I need to send a list of image files.

My Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddImage(string emailid , List<IFormFile> imagefile)
{
    ImageUpload img=new ImageUpload();
    var emailId = feedBackContext.UserMasters.FirstOrDefault(m=>m.Email==emailid);
    foreach (var item in imagefile)
    {
        if (item.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                img.imagefile = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

    }

    img.EmailID = emailId.UserMasterID;
    var existimage = feedBackContext.ImageUpload.FirstOrDefault(m => m.EmailID == emailId.UserMasterID);
    if (existimage == null)
    {
        feedBackContext.ImageUpload.Add(img);
        feedBackContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        feedBackContext.ImageUpload.Remove(existimage);
        feedBackContext.SaveChanges();
        feedBackContext.ImageUpload.Add(img);
        feedBackContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

My JavaScript file:
(I need to send array of image files to the controller like passing array)

```
function sendArr(form)
var []=imgarr;
{     

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            url: form.action,
            data: { dataList: arr, imageList: imgarr },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (asd) {
                document.getElementById("QuestionDescription").value = "";
                document.getElementById("AnswerDescription").value = "";
                count = 0;
                $('#demo').remove();

                document.getElementById("QuestionDescription").focus();
                window.location.href = '';
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Form::

```
<script>
function addAnswer() {

imgarr[count] = document.getElementById('imagefile').value;

}
</script>

<form asp-action="AddImage">
<input type="file" id="imagefile" name="imagefile"  />
</form>
```

Help me if you know something regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your **form** looks similar to this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

  <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

  <input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

**Controller:**
You need to use `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {
  foreach (var file in files) {
    if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
      var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
      file.SaveAs(path);
    }
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The `files` variable refers to the name attribute in the form fields.

You can also stuff the variable inside a model if you like.

Example taken from [here](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/)

Comment: problem is I'musing dot net core.so HttpPostedFileBase is not recognized here.if you know someting  let me know

Comment: Ah. You did not tag your question as .net core. IFormFile is the .net core equivalent of MVC6. Please update your question to show your form fields as your controller should be working. I will update my answer once I see your form code.

Comment: I've updated the form.but this is save not as a form submission. Form is just to get the url and get the input value

Comment: I don’t think you can submit files that way. It’s a security concern to be able to access the file data with JavaScript. You need to post the form or find a library that can help the upload feel asynchronous.

Comment: This won't work. If you have a multiple file upload fields like this, you'd have to use array notation for the name (i.e. `files[]`), otherwise only the first one will be submitted.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Model binder should handle it if you submit the form normally. Please take a look at the link in my answer, it was provided by a Microsoft dev.

Comment: This is a basic HTML limitation. If you have multiple inputs with the same name, only the first is submitted unless the name uses array notation.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You're mistaken. I just tried the example, and both files are showing up in my controller action. If you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` it all goes up.